# Regex : Replace text between semicolons a certain amount of times

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i'm a bit confused with regex, i have a line which looks like something like this :

`test = "article;vendor;qty;desc;price1;price2"`

and what i'm trying to do is to only get price1.
I'm currently using this function :

`Regex.Replace(test, @".*;[^;]*;", "");`

which permit me to get price2 but I can't see how I can isolate price1.

Comment: `var price2 = test.Split(';')[4];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider just using a [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) call instead to break your current semi-colon delimited string into an array :

```
var input = "article;vendor;qty;desc;price1;price2";
var output = input.Split(';');
```

And then you could simply access your value by its index :

```
var result = output[4]; // yields "price1"
```

You will only want to use a Regular Expression if there is a specific pattern that you can use to match and select exactly what you are looking for, but for delimited lists, the `String.Split()` method will usually make things easier (especially if there is nothing to uniquely identify the item you are trying to pull from the list).

Comment: You are totally right, I wonder why I was searching to complicated things, thanks you.

Comment: No problem. Regular Expressions certainly have their uses, but they can commonly become a "hammer" that might be overused for things a bit outside of their scope. So while you *could* use one here, it may not be the best approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
(?:[^;]*;){4}([^;]*);
```

And replace the first match group.